# Why is there a 2n+1 comparison for a linear search algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

Suppose an algorithm goes through a list of n integers and for every iteration of the loop it is needs to check if the current evaluated element of the list is even. If it is even, return the index of the integer that is evaluated as even.

How come the algorithm would have 2n+1 comparison?

I thought linear search would have n comparision because it is going through n elements. +1 comparison for the if statement. So that would make the algorithm O(n+1) comparison, no?. Where did the extra n come from?

Pseudo-code:

```
procedure last_even_loc(a1,a2,...,an:integers);
location = 0;
for i = 1 to n

    if (a_i = 0) (mod 2) then location = i

return location;
```

Comment: Your algorithm has at most $n$ comparisons. As an aside, $O(n+1) = O(n)$ is any function which is bounded by $Cn$, which is presumably not what you meant when writing that the algorithm would make $O(n+1)$ comparisons.

Comment: Right the algorithm would have at most n comparision because the algorithm has O(n+1) comparisons.

Comment: That's not quite correct. If an algorithm has $O(n+1)$ comparisons then it might have more than $n$ comparisons. For example, an algorithm making $10n+17$ comparisons also has $O(n+1)$ comparisons. Also, $O(n+1)$ is the same as $O(n)$. Make sure that you understand the meaning of big O notation.

Comment: the way I understand big O notation informally speaking is when f(x) is less than or equal to g(x). example: n big O n^2, where f(x) is n and g(x) is n^2.

Comment: Your understanding is incomplete, then. I suggest you review the definition of big O. We say that $f(n) = O(g(n))$ if there is some constant $C > 0$ such that for large enough $n$, $f(n) \leq C g(n)$. In your description, you are missing the constant $C$.

Comment: If you're asking why an O(n) algorithm can use 2n + 1 operations, you should read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
procedure last_even_loc(a1,a2,...,an:integers)
1.location = 0;
2.for i = 1 to n
3.    if (a_i = 0) (mod 2) then location = i
4.return location;
```

statement 1 is executing only once.
statemet 2 is executing total n+1 times.
statement 3 is executing total n times.
statement 4 is executing only once.

The running time of the algorithm is the sum of running time of all the statements executed.so running time=1+1+n+(n+1)=O(2n+3)=O(n).so there is total n+1+n=2n+1 comparisons(statement 2 and 3).

Comment: How come statement executes n+1 times. Should it be n times because it is going through the list of size n? How come statement executes n times? Should 1+1+n+(n+1) be 2n+3?

Comment: See statement 2 is executing total n+1 times, result of first n comparison test is true, and then n+1 th test become false then the loop terminates(then not executing statement 3).so statement 3 which is inside the loop executed total n times.And your question is about number of comparison which is total number of execution of statement 2+statement 3.

Comment: is your question about why O(2n+3)=O(n)?

Comment: You had O(2n+1) when you did the first sum. But should it not be O(2n+3) because of the three 1's?

Comment: OK I have edited my answer.now tell me what is your confusion exactly?

Comment: Now that you edited the answer, I have questions. Why does statement 2 or more specifically going through a list of size n have n+1 comparisons instead of n comparisons? I still not sure why statement 3 have n comparisons. The idea does not click with me.

Comment: Consider n=4. initially i=1.comparisons inside the for statement: 1<=4 ->True.2<=4->True. 3<=4->True.4<=4->True.And 5<=4->False.so total no of comparison=5=n+1.Similarly statement 3 executed total n times. because for the last comparison inside for statement which is 5<=4, statement 3 will not be executed. now is there any confusion?

Comment: So it is going through n elements(which gives it th n) plus the extra check which is false(which gives it the +1) putting these facts gives it n + 1?

Comment: exactly. And as it becomes false so statement 3 which is inside the for loop will get executed n times.

Comment: How come runtime includes statement 2 and 3? But not 1 and 4?

Comment: see for this specific program the matter of worst case/best case comes only in statement 3.more rigorously the IF statement is executing n times but what inside the if statement is O(n), indicating at most n times execution.

Comment: runtime includes all 1,2,3 and 4(see my answer).But number of comparison includes only 2 and 3 as in statement 2 and 3 there are comparison statements.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks for the help, tan! It is great what a continued discussion can do for the confused mind.

Comment: 3n+3 is worst case.Best case 2n+3.see in worst case there is another n because of location=i

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the help on the analysis. I did not even see the extra n for location = i in worse case! Is there a discrete mathematic or discrete structure textbook you would recommend to me?

Comment: @Nicholas: I have already pointed it out in my comment.The IF statement is executing n times but what inside the if statement is O(n), indicating at most n times execution.Now see in best case the outcome of all the comparisons of the IF statement are FALSE.So the statement inside the IF statement i,e lication=i; will never get executed.That is why best case time complexity=O(2n+3).The worst case is that when all comparisons of the IF statement are TRUE.so the statement inside IF statement i,e location=i; will be executed n times in worst case.then total time complexity=O(2n+3+n)=O(3n+3).

Comment: @Nicholas: I would recommend the popular [Introduction to Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms).Try to start reading it from the first chapter.